# find 3rd record of 3rd highest salary from employee table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a employee table with their name ,dept , salary as column .
I want  to get the 3rd employee whose salary comes into 3rd heigest category

```
empl    dept    salary
sant    x   3000
temb    x   4000
porty   z   4000
xati    x   2000
tres    t   3000
werbt   z   2000
amiq    t   3000
```

desired result :
amiq    t   3000

what will be the query ?

Comment: By what do you order your employees who are in the same category?

Comment: third highest category of salary is 2000 and you are asking for the result who has 2 highest category of salary i.e 3000 which doesn't makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives:

```
SELECT *  FROM TableName ORDER BY Salary DESC,empl LIMIT 2,1
```

Fiddle example [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e5876/11).

**OR:**

```
SELECT empl,dept,salary
FROM
(SELECT T.*,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM TableName T,(SELECT @rownum := 0) as R
ORDER BY T.Salary DESC,empl) as T2
WHERE rank=3
```

Result:

```
EMPL    DEPT    SALARY
amiq    t       3000
```

**Explanation:**

The query will select the records with a rank in descending order of salary. **Advantage** is that you can find the nth highest salary by replacing 3 by n (which ofcourse, ordered by `empl`).

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e5876/8).

Comment: But OP said that the result should be: amiq of department t ... not sant of department x

Comment: @VMai: See the edited answer. It will select `amiq` of department `t`

Comment: @RagingBull : this query is also giving result .   SELECT empl,dept,salary FROM TableName T where salary = (select salary from TableName T order by salary desc limit 2,1) order by salary desc limit 2,1 . i have tried to compare execution time of both my ur query and result is almost same (1ms diff).

Comment: @user1132609: Ofcourse, but that seems complicated. Why do you want to use an inner query when you can use `ORDER BY Salary DESC,empl`?

Comment: @RagingBull : Thank you for imprompt solution .trying to understand workflow of ur query , so that the best query can be written for a table of large records .

Comment: @user1132609: Its a pleasure, my friend. Please feel free to ask if you have doubts in my query.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name b ORDER BY  empl) b  
ORDER  BY  salary desc LIMIT 2,1
```

Comment: this query will give : sant    x   3000

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM employee ORDER BY Salary DESC,empl LIMIT 2,1
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e4455/1)

Comment: this query will give result : sant    x   3000

Comment: @user1132609 check now mate

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and sort Query**

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (
       SELECT * FROM <Table Name> b ORDER BY  empl desc
    ) b  
    ORDER  BY  salary desc 
    LIMIT 2,1
```

**Result:-**

> ```
>       empl   dept   salary
>       amiq    t      3000
> ```

Comment: and if you have trillion row?